# How to bind an input type 'time' in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I assumed it was something like this but it doesn't work -

HTML:

```
<input id="timePicker" type="time" placeholder="HH:MM" required="" data-bind="value: timeFrom">
```

JS:

```
self.timeFrom = ko.observable("8:00");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be set to `"08:00"`:

```
self.timeFrom = ko.observable("08:00");
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqf7zq3/)